# Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis

I am consuming web service developed in the .net which accepts username and password as part of the SOAP header. I created SOAPHandler to create the header.

I printed the message it is like below:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

 <wsse:UsernameToken>
 <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
 <wsse:Password>xxxxxxxx</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
```

When I hit the service I am receiving below error.

```
[4/3/16 18:53:10:342 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must
> Understand check failed for header
> http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
> : Security
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:343 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:343 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:343 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:343 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:586)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:343 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:130)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:344 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:344 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:391)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:344 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:208)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:344 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.authenticateSP(Unknown Source)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:344 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.id3global.id3gws._2013._04.IGlobalAuthenticate_BasicHttpBindingGlobalAuthenticate_Client.main(IGlobalAuthenticate_BasicHttpBindingGlobalAuthenticate_Client.java:90)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:345 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.eeft.ws.ppd.EwalletBalanceInquiryWSBeanPortBindingImpl.ewalletBalanceInquiry(EwalletBalanceInquiryWSBeanPortBindingImpl.java:104)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:345 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:345 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:345 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:345 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:345 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.java.JavaDispatcher.invokeMethod(JavaDispatcher.java:203)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.java.JavaDispatcher.invokeOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:158)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.SoapRPCProcessor.processRequestResponse(SoapRPCProcessor.java:490)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.SoapRPCProcessor.processMessage(SoapRPCProcessor.java:433)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.BasicDispatcher.processMessage(BasicDispatcher.java:134)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.java.SessionDispatcher.invoke(SessionDispatcher.java:204)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:263)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandler.invoke(JAXRPCHandler.java:153)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:346 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.WrappedHandler.invoke(WrappedHandler.java:64)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:263)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:263)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesEngine.invoke(WebServicesEngine.java:336)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServlet.doPost(WebServicesServlet.java:1246)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServletBase.service(WebServicesServletBase.java:344)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:347 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1700)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:348 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:349 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header
> http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
> : Security
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:350 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:127)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:191)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:363)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:581)
>     [4/3/16 18:53:10:351 EET] 00000027 SystemErr     R    ... 50 more
```

I removed the mustunderstand tag and changed value to zero still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed to override the `getHeaders()` method in the handler. Below post helped me to add the handler it started working.

[SOAPFaultException "MustUnderstand headers (oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd) are not understood"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364428/soapfaultexception-mustunderstand-headers-oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1?rq=1)

```
@Override 
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() { 
        QName securityHeader = new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", 
                "Security"); 
        HashSet<QName> headers = new HashSet<QName>(); 
        headers.add(securityHeader);         
        return headers; 
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? I am not able to fix this error.