# How can I enable ws-addressing in spring so that replyTo is understood?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jax-ws, ws-addressing

I created a ws endpoint with spring using spring-boot-starter-webservices.

I have used `@org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint`.It works fine.

But when I am trying to add the `wsa:ReplyTo` addressing header to the request with `mustUnderstand=true` the server prints:

> Could not handle mustUnderstand headers: {http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}ReplyTo. Returning fault

and returns a similar Fault as a response.

How can I enable addressing so that `ReplyTo` is understood and replies with `202`, sending the response to the differrent endpoint described in `ReplyTo`?

I tried adding `@javax.xml.ws.soap.Addressing(enabled=true)` next to `@Endpoint` annotation but I still get the above behaviour.

Comment: Please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364428/soapfaultexception-mustunderstand-headers-oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1


and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260277/could-not-handle-mustunderstand-headers-http-docs-oasis-open-org-wss-2004-01

If they can help you

Comment: @JCompetence My understanding is that the above links show how you can ignore these  headers even when the `mustUnderstand=true` exists. What I need is to  enable spring in understanding them so that it acts according to what the specification describes about these headers (E.g. for `ReplyTo` send the response to another endpoint).

Comment: Please add your endpoint code